# How to open a different links in the same activity and webView using different buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

For example the first page we have three buttons all the buttons open the same activity (`SecondActivity`) but every button open a different link in the webview of this activity, more details:

- Button 1: OPEN `SecondActivity` and his WebView open the link: `www.firstlink.com`
- Button 2: OPEN `SecondActivity` and his WebView open the link: `www.secondlink.com`
- Button 3: OPEN `SecondActivity` and his WebView open the link: `www.thirdlink.com`

THIS image may explain it more

[image: THIS image my explain it more]

I'm searching for a `KOTLIN` code to do that, Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From button 1 click listener -

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
// To pass any data to another activity
intent.putExtra("targetURL", "www.firstlink.com")
// start your SecondActivity
startActivity(intent)
```

Similarly from button2 click listener -

```
intent.putExtra("targetURL", "www.secondlink.com")
```

Similarly from button3 click listener -

```
intent.putExtra("targetURL", "www.thirdlink.com")
```

in the `SecondActivity`, do -

```
var url: String = intent.getStringExtra("value")?: "" // the default value is ""
```

Assuming there is a value in `url`, load it in your `webview` reference.

Comment: this is the relevant code examples, if you are expecting someone will write everything for you then please SO isn't the right place.

Comment: i have an error wich says           "        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medanis.fneclis/com.medanis.fneclis.License}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: webv must not be null "

Comment: webv is my webview ID / class License : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var url: String = intent.getStringExtra("value")?: ""
        webv.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        startActivity(intent)

    }
} // this is my code in the second activity

Comment: that's another problem, so if the answer solved your problem, accept it. and post another question with code blocks. Maybe someone else will be able to help you. who knows!